# How can i find that rows that have MIN of 1 column and Max of 1 column together?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my query

```
SELECT s1.* FROM tbl s1 
JOIN ( 
SELECT ID, MIN(Overall_Rank) AS rank, MAX(Service_Duration) AS duration FROM tbl 
)
AS s2 ON s1.ID = s2.ID AND s1.Overall_Rank= s2.rank AND s1.Service_Duration=s2.duration
```

What i would like to do is **get the Rows that has Min.value of Overall_Rank and in that has Max.value of Service_Duration**. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with above query??

Answer (score 0):

Don't really get what you want.

How about this?

SELECT * 
FROM tbl
WHERE Overall_Rank = (SELECT MIN(Overall_Rank) FROM tbl)
  AND Service_Duration = (SELECT MAX(Service_Duration) FROM tbl)

Comment: To speed up this query add indexes to the two columns

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Service_Duration = (
SELECT MAX(Service_Duration) FROM tbl WHERE Overall_Rank = (SELECT MIN(Overall_Rank) FROM tbl))
```

Assuming that I have understood you correctly, you are interested in returning the rows with the lowest `Overall_Rank` which have got maximum value in `Service_Duration` column.

EDIT:
To speed it up you can try to create indexes on Service_Duration and Overall_Rank, as someone suggested.

I don't know what kind of code executes this SQL query (Java, PHP?), but perhaps it would be easier to do it in two separate queries? I am not an expert in MySQL area, but I suppose that doing subquery in subquery is not optimal here.

Comment: Yes, you have understood it correctly. But the query you suggest takes much time to execute. Is there any other way?